# How do you update a custom DateTime object in C#?

Tags: c#

Here is a custom DateTime object:

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2017, 5, 12, 5, 0, 0);
```

I would like to update dt not every millisecond, but when I call updateTime().

My general pseudo plan:

```
void updateTime() { 
   TimeSpan lapsedTime = new TimeSpan(??) // Get lapsed time since application started
   m_myCustomDate += lapsedTime; 
}
```

How do I put the time difference duration into TimeSpan?

Comment: You need to create time span with the duration for which you are doing thread sleep. `new TimeSpan(0,0,5);`

Comment: Your timespan TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second); should contain timeduration to be added, not hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: If you want to *measure* the time elapsed you'd use either `Stopwatch` (via the Elapsed property) or you would take the difference between two DateTimes (porbably obtained from DateTime.Now). Either of those is a TimeSpan.

Comment: Who calls updatetime method? When it is called? Any specific interval? You need to track the last time it was updated. So that you can you know the difference between that and current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do that much work to get time since application started. `Process` class already provides `Process.StartTime` that you can subtract from `DateTime.Now` to get total time since your application started.

So instead of all of the above, you can do the following whenever you need total application time:

```
var AppTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime).TotalSeconds;
```

There are other properties like `TotalMinutes` and `TotalHours` that you can choose instead of TotalSeconds.

Comment: TimeSpan  doesn't accept seconds but the number of ticks, at least with the constructor I'm using. I ended up doing this: 
DateTime.Now.Ticks - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime.Ticks. It works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Phil: `Ticks` is just another unit of time in .NET, equal to 100 nano-seconds. So it is one and the same thing whether you choose Ticks, Milliseconds, Seconds or Hours. Choose whatever is most appropriate for your use.